# Rails How To List all Images in a Folder using the image_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im trying to take all the images in the 'app/assets/images/slide' folder and put them withing  tags (in order). So, it will look like this :

```
<img src="1.jpg" >
<img src="2.jpg" >
<img src="3.jpg" >
```

How can I achive this? (Im using Rails 3.2.9)

Here's the code I tried (thanks to Khaled). But it outputs a plain text list of all image paths. I need the images to show :

```
@images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/slide/*.jpg")

@images.each do |image|
    image_tag image.gsub("app/assets/images/", "")
end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your controller action, get all images paths.

```
@images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/slide/*.jpg")
```

Then in your view (assuming haml)

```
- @images.each do |image|
   = image_tag "slide/#{image.split('/').last}"
```

Assuming erb

```
 <% @images.each do |image| %>
   <%= image_tag "slide/#{image.split('/').last}" %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: It just prints a list of the image paths like this  :   ["app/assets/images/slide/6.jpg", "app/assets/images/slide/1.jpg", "app/assets/images/slide/3.jpg", "app/assets/images/slide/7.jpg", "app/assets/images/slide/2.jpg", "app/assets/images/slide/5.jpg", "app/assets/images/slide/8.jpg", "app/assets/images/slide/4.jpg"]

Comment: are you sure you are using the `image_tag` helper ?

Comment: Here's the code I tried (I use .html.erb)  images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/slide/*.jpg")

images.each do |image|
   image_tag image
end

Comment: Thanks a lot :) In your code, the image.split didn't work. But I added "image_tag image.gsub("app/assets/images/", "")" instead and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing... It doesn't come in the correct order. How to fix this?

Comment: How would you go about also adding png and gif to that?

Thanks for this answer btw.

Comment: should you not be naming the directory "slides" rather than "slide"? Because of convention and all? Not too sure though, just assuming... :)

Comment: @marczking: I guess u are right, but the name here is irrelevant and I am trying to give an example that is as close as to the question asked, so I would stick with 'slide' in this example.

Answer (score 4):

To ensure the operation, you can use:

```
@images = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/camisas/*.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me and displays images:

```
Dir.glob('app/assets/images/slide/*').map do |path| 
  image_tag "slide/#{ File.basename(path) }"
end.reduce(&:+)
```

You want to get rid of the full path with File#basename so it works with precompiled assets afaik. You also don't need to specify .jpg because its an images folder, and could have .png's.

Comment: FYI, you have a typo in 'image_tag' (iamge_tag).

Answer (score 0):

```
files = Dir.glob('app/assets/images/slide/*')
files.each do |file|
  puts file
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, `image_tag` returns an html image tag for the source. It cannot show all images at once. You should make a custom helper to read and walk through your directory.