# Ruby displaying "InvalidURIError" when certain string is put through regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, image, uri

I'm attempting to grab the URL of every image within a directory and display them with image_tag(s), but Ruby was appending "images/" in front of the image src and made them not work.

I tried to rectify this by removing everything before the name of the subdirectory in the images folder but it caused an error and only with that one specific word.

Using HAML

```
@models = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/creation/model/*.png")
@i = 0;

- @models.each do |model|
      - @i++
        %td{:id => "#{@i}"}
          %img= image_tag model.gsub!(/.*?(?=creation)/im, "")
```

Inserting "creation" breaks it, inserting seemingly anything else is fine.

Was there something I did wrong?

---

Update: I tried renaming the folder and changing the code accordingly, same thing happened. Inserting the name of the folder with one character changed doesn't display an error and renders nothing, but as soon as you put in the actual name you get "InvalidURIError"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails How To List all Images in a Folder using the image\_tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081109/rails-how-to-list-all-images-in-a-folder-using-the-image-tag)

Comment: The problem is "creation", it breaks it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Upon taking a look at the error I realized that Rails was taking issue with a single image's filename, I guess it had characters in it that Rails didn't like.

Weird, I've used the same image in a PHP application fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
%img= image_tag URI.encode("creation/model/#{model.split('/').last}")
```

Comment: Same error, the keyword is "creation". Making the string "asdf/model/#{model.split('/').last}" doesn't render any images but it doesn't display an error.

Comment: It should work. You need to go and check generated url in web developer console in your browser. Just click on it with the right mouse button and select "Inspect".

Comment: Inspect element doesn't work because Rails is rendering an error, but upon you saying that I took a look at the error and realized it was taking issue with a single image's file name.

Comment: Maybe it's some space in your filename. I've updated my answer, try it.